# drang and drop between three lists using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have three sortable lists using Jquery UI. all-colls-list, coll-selected-list and coll-grouped-list. They are all identifiable with their IDs.

I wish to be able to drag and drop between all-colls-list and coll-selected-list and vice-versa all-colls-list and coll-grouped-list and vice-versa

I don't want to be able to drag and drop between coll-selected-list and coll-grouped-list.

My code however doesn't agree to this and only allows me to drop between all-colls-list and coll-grouped-list and vice-versa. Any help will be much appreciated.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/NkQBy/

```
var lists = [{
    "listid": "#all-colls-list",
    "connectid": "#coll-selected-list",
    "drop": true
}, {
    "listid": "#coll-selected-list",
    "connectid": "#all-colls-list",
    "drop": true
}, {
    "listid": "#all-colls-list",
    "connectid": "#coll-grouped-list",
    "drop": true
}, {
    "listid": "#coll-grouped-list",
    "connectid": "#all-colls-list",
    "drop": true
}];

$.each(lists, function (i, list) {
    $(list.listid).sortable({
        connectWith: list.connectid,
        dropOnEmpty: list.drop,
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            $("#all-colls-list li").css("background-image", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi there, I assume my answer below wasn't what you were after. If I'm right please just let me know and I'll have another crack at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting the `.sortable` `connectWith` property.
You need to set multiple targets in a single instance (or more cleverly...)

Here is [your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/NkQBy/1/). I think that is what you are after?

Hope it helps! :)